# How to comma to alphanumeric numbers in text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a text where it is mix up of all alphanumeric values...
for example like this

```
ACETAMINOPHEN 250 MG ASPIRIN65 MG CAFFEINE

ACER NEGUNDO POLLEN0.0021 G/ML ACER RUBRUM POLLEN0.0021 G/ML ACER SACCHARINUM POLLEN0.0021 G/ML ACER SACCHARUM POLLEN
```

So my requirement is i need to add comma (,) before every number value in this text.The text is different from each other.But main one what ever the number is there need to add comma before that one (decimal,numeric etc)

```
ACETAMINOPHEN,250 MG ASPIRIN,65 MG CAFFEINE

ACER NEGUNDO POLLEN,0.0021 G/ML ACER RUBRUM POLLEN,0.0021 G/ML ACER SACCHARINUM POLLEN,0.0021 G/ML ACER SACCHARUM POLLEN
```

Suggest me ???

Comment: This sounds like a problem to throw a regular expression at, if you can enable them within your server?

Comment: Just a comment but that should be normalized in a table with columns drug and dose.

Comment: In some places you are replaces a space.  In other places, you are adding a new character.  Are both of these part of the problem?  Or can you just add a comma, even when there is a space before it?

Answer (score 1):

This will require Regular Expressions. If you're using SQL Server 2008 or above, it will probably be easier to write a .NET function that uses `RegEx` object to achieve this. You can then call that function (.NET assembly function) in your `UPDATE` query to modify your data. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) if you're interested.

Alternately you can uses DataSets or other .NET level data access methods to achieve the same.

Comment: is there any way to do in back end like using patindex        DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(50) SET @str = 'ACARBOSE25 mg/1 ACARBOSE' IF PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @str) > 0`                                  we can find the numeric in text but how to add comma before numeric

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: If you mean some Stored Proc, then yes, I guess that is possible, but will take more effort to code all corner cases etc.

Comment: You can use stuff function to add the comma, but its kinda tricky to find the pattern in this string:                                            select STUFF('ACETAMINOPHEN 250 MG ASPIRIN65 MG CAFFEINE',patindex('%[0-9]%','ACETAMINOPHEN 250 MG ASPIRIN65 MG CAFFEINE')+1, 0 , ',' )

Comment: Could and should are not the same.  You might get there with patindex but this is a job for regex.